Touchpad lag after two fingers scroll
I didn't know where to post this issue and thought this was the best place to start. I recently tried a number of linux distros on my job's laptop and always encountered this issue. I tested and confirmed the issue on X11 with synaptics drivers, X11 with libinput and Wayland. Tried GNOME on fedora, Ubuntu desktop, XFCE on Kubuntu and KDE on Kubuntu. The problem is still there.
The problem:
At first, the touchpad works normally. After initiating a two finger scroll action, the touchpad becomes laggy: the pointer on the screen moves with a pretty obivious input lag, making the experience very unpleasant. When in this state of lagginess, if the touchpad doesn't receive any input for 5 seconds, it gets back to working normally again. Triggering a two finger scroll will make it laggy again until no input is received for at least 5 seconds.
This is not a libinput issue, not a synaptics drivers issue, not a DE issue, so could it be hardware? But the same machine works well on windows, with the touchpad perfectly responsive. Plus it is only a transient state, so the hardware is capable of working as intended, looks like a driver issue to me but I'm not really sure where should I open an issue.
I am facing this issue on a Lenovo V15 G3
A video showing the issue: https://youtube.com/shorts/gO4YvUimoYE?feature=share
Any help or idea would be greatly appreciated
